# How do I run a joined subquery once together for all rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do something like this:

```
SELECT T.*, X.Val
FROM SomeTable T
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 A.[Value] AS Val FROM AnotherTable A ORDER BY A.Id DESC) X ON X.Val = X.Val
```

The goal is to get a single value from a subquery and join/apply it to all rows of my record set. The value from the subquery is the same for all rows and is independent on them. So it would be efficient to run the subquery only once, and then only use the retrieved value for all rows. But based on the query running time, it seems that the subquery is running for each row again which is slow. The same was for other ways I tried like outer apply etc.

In fact, my subquery looks like this:

```
(SELECT dbo.MyScalarFunction() AS Val) X
```

But I hope it shouldn't matter. The scalar function itself is running some 1 sec., so it must run only once in the whole query, I can't wait thousand seconds for thousand rows in the record set.

Is there a way to enforce running the subquery only once before joining it?

I am inside of a view, so I can't use a declared variable to store the subquery value.

Comment: A SQL query is just source code, the *server* simplifies it, compiles it into an execution plan based on the tables indexes and data statistics, and finally executes that plan. If you think you have to control the execution order, somethings's wrong. For example, that `TOP 1` could delay execution because it forces the subquery to run for each outer query. You could use the `LAST_VALUE` function instead. Which is faster? You'd have to compare the actual execution plans

Comment: `The scalar function itself is running some 1 sec` that's *very* wrong - a scalar function that takes an entire second to execute is actually a very slow stored procedure in disguise. At the very least, it should be calculated *before* the query and stored in a variable.  What are you trying to do? Describe the *actual* queries and tables, not how you think the query should work

Comment: The scalar function actually looks like this: dbo.getLocalizedLabel('LabelCode') and it's retrieving a translated value of a label specified by the code in the parameter. Unfortunately, the application localization is stored in an XML file, and in the DB there is only a copy of the file content stored as nvarchar(max) in one table. So the scalar function must parse the nvarchar as xml, find the right node and return its value. I would agree that this is a bad solution, but I'm not deciding about the application architecture.

Comment: Scalar functions are notoriously slow, unless you're using the new inline functionality in 2019. Scalar functions, otherwise, must be a multi-line function as inline scalar functions don't exist in all currently (production) released versions. I *suspect* you'll be significantly better off using an inline table-value function. Without the DDL of the function, however, it'll be impossible for us to tell you how to do that.

Comment: What I need is to get a translated "No category" label for records not belonging to any category (otherwise I use category name which is not needed to translate). Of course it would be a natural solution to store the value to a variable first, but as I stated, I'm inside of a view so the whole query can be only one select statement, I can't declare variables.

Comment: @Mouser you're abusing functions in that case. to do complex processing inside a view. Don't do that. In relational theory views are called `virtual tables`. What you describe isn't a virtual table. At best, it's should be considered a function itself. Worst case, it's a stored procedure

Comment: As for the xml, store it in an `xml`-typed field and index the field. Copy it there if you have to. That's the only way to improve what is rather bad query performance. After all, you shouldn't have to *parse* the XML data unless it changes. Doing so in every query is a waste of time already

Comment: To explain about your point *"But based on the query running time, it seems that the subquery is running for each row again which is slow."* because that is **exactly** what it is doing: [Why Scalar Functions Can Be Costly](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/why-scalar-functions-can-be-costly)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you phrasing this as coming from another table?  Based on your later question, why not just use `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT T.*, X.Val
FROM SomeTable T CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT dbo.MyScalarFunction() AS Val) X
```

I cannot see how the function would be called more than once, unless it is a recursive function.

Comment: I tried, but it runs as long as the other options. I will have to change the approach and not use the view, as was discussed above in the comments. But thanks anyway

Comment: @Mouser . . . In that case, the timing is probably related to the volume of data and not to the use of the scalar function.